# Install Laravel - OpenSSL issue

Tags: php, laravel, openssl, composer-php

I am trying to create a new Laravel project on Mac (MacOs Sierra 10.12.6). 
I tried:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel –-prefer-dist
```

I get the following error message:

**ERROR**

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>   The
>   "https://packagist.org/p/laravel/laravel%244ce56dd29ae53500d408bd75166f
>   ef028bdf1bc4b420d6ee5f28793bc5537084.json" file could not be
>   downloaded: SS     L operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error
>   messages:                         error:1407742E:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol ver     sion
>   Failed to enable crypto
>   failed to open stream: operation failed

I tried to run a `composer diagnose` and here are the results:

1) Checking platform settings: **WARNING**

> The OpenSSL library (0.9.8y) used by PHP does not support TLSv1.2 or
>   TLSv1.1. If possible you should upgrade OpenSSL to version 1.0.1 or
>   above.

if I check the `openssl version`, the result is OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019.

2) Checking https connectivity to packagist: **WARNING**

The error message is the same as the one I get when I try to create a Laravel project

3) Checking github.com rate limit: **FAIL**

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The
>   "https://api.github.com/rate_limit" file could not be downloaded: SSL
>   operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert
>   protocol version Failed to enable crypto failed to open stream:
>   operation failed

4) Checking composer version:

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>   The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded:
>   SSL: C     onnection reset by peer
>   Failed to enable crypto
>   failed to open stream: operation failed

Composer version: 1.9.1
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1d
PHP version:
PHP 7.4.0 (cli) (built: Dec  2 2019 15:07:44) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies with Zend OPcache v7.4.0, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

What should I do ?

Comment: Are you facing similar problem if you try to add any other composer package? e.g in a empty directory run `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle` if you facing problem in that there might be some issue with composer or php configuration. Another note I want to add latest laravel required `PHP >= 7.2.0`. your php cli version is 7.0

Comment: also check with `php -m` it should list openssl extension. if it's not there that could be the issue.

Comment: I tried `php -m`, openssl is listed.

Comment: `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle` does not work. I have the same error message. I installed php 7.4 but when I do `php --version` it still says 7.0.0...

Comment: you need to update php path as per latest you have.

Comment: `php --version` now returns PHP 7.4.0 (cli) (built: Dec  2 2019 15:07:44) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.0, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

Comment: now check with `php -m`, it should list openssl.

Comment: It does list openssl but it does from the beginning...
The composer version is now 1.9.1. When I do `composer create-project laravel/laravel –-prefer-dist` I only have the second error message:
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                     
  The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded  
  : SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:                  
  error:1407742E:SSL routines ... ...

Comment: if you change php path, it also change loaded extension and php.ini being used.